# Issue while creating a job for AWS Elemental media convert

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

I am having some issue while creating a job for AWS Elemental media convert.
I have followed the following sequence.

1.) Create a new job

2.) Add input and configurations

3.) Add File output group and configure destination settings

4.) Under Output change Container to No Container

5.) Under Output remove Audio

6.) Under Output -> Video change Codec to JPEG to Frame Capture

7.) Configure frame rate (rate which captures will be produced (more notes and examples below))

8.) Configure max capture settings

I got the following error:

> Job_contains_the_following_error:
>   /outputGroups: Should not match the schema

**Here is my job JSON:**

```
{
  "Settings": {
    "AdAvailOffset": 0,
    "Inputs": [
  {
    "FilterEnable": "AUTO",
    "PsiControl": "USE_PSI",
    "FilterStrength": 0,
    "DeblockFilter": "DISABLED",
    "DenoiseFilter": "DISABLED",
    "TimecodeSource": "EMBEDDED",
    "VideoSelector": {
      "ColorSpace": "FOLLOW",
      "Rotate": "DEGREE_0"
    },
    "AudioSelectors": {
      "Audio Selector 1": {
        "Offset": 0,
        "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT",
        "ProgramSelection": 1
      }
    },
    "FileInput": "s3://field-live-user-data/udariyan.mp4"
  }
],
"OutputGroups": [
  {
    "Name": "File Group",
    "OutputGroupSettings": {
      "Type": "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
      "FileGroupSettings": {
        "Destination": "s3://field-live-user-data/"
      }
    },
    "Outputs": [
      {
        "VideoDescription": {
          "ScalingBehavior": "DEFAULT",
          "TimecodeInsertion": "DISABLED",
          "AntiAlias": "ENABLED",
          "Sharpness": 50,
          "CodecSettings": {
            "Codec": "FRAME_CAPTURE",
            "FrameCaptureSettings": {
              "FramerateNumerator": 30,
              "FramerateDenominator": 100,
              "MaxCaptures": 2,
              "Quality": 80
            }
          },
          "DropFrameTimecode": "ENABLED",
          "ColorMetadata": "INSERT",
          "Width": 1280,
          "Height": 720
        },
        "ContainerSettings": {
          "Container": "RAW"
        },
        "Extension": "jpg"
      }
    ],
    "CustomName": "customGroup"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Queue": "arn:aws:mediaconvert:us-east-1:469030323850:queues/Default",
  "Role": "arn:aws:iam::469030323850:role/myMediaConverter"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you can't have a job template with frame capture only:

[AWS Dev forums on this topic](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=829699&tstart=0)